# Count number of values in pandas that increment by 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
df = 

sample_type    data_window    value
   A                4           0.6
   A                5           0.1
   A                6           1.2
   B                1           0.5
   B                7           0.3
   B                8           0.8
   C                2           1.4
   C                3           0.7
```

For each `sample_type`, how can I get the number of rows where `data_window` increments by exactly 1?

For example, for `sample_type` = A, I get an output where number of consecutive `data_window` occurences = 2, for `sample_type` = B, I get an output where number of consecutive `data_window` occurences = 1, and for `sample_type` = C, I get an output where number of consecutive `data_window` occurences = 1?

Could I use something like `df['data_window'].diff()` and count per subject somehow?

Comment: If you have a D type like : 3, 4, 8, 11, 12, 13. What should be the result? 3 because (3, 4), (11, 12) and (12, 13) or 2 because the max consecutive is (11, 12) and (12, 13)?

Comment: Hm..good point. Ideally, I'd like to capture the size of consecutive numbers in some way, but not sure how. So for type D, I'm trying to get the output to be = 2. In that case the consecutive pairs are (3, 4) and (11, 12, 13).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `.diff()`, then just do `.eq(1).sum()`.

```
df.groupby('sample_type').apply(
    lambda sf: sf['data_window'].diff().eq(1).sum())
```

```
sample_type
A    2
B    1
C    1
dtype: int64
```